# TextArea focus attribute is not working with Ant Design

Tags: javascript, antd

I am using an Ant Design TextArea field in one of my web pages, but when I am trying to set the focus (expecting the blinking cursor in the textArea), it is not working.

```js
 <TextArea
    className=""
    style={{
      fontFamily: "Sen",
      color: "#191919",
    }}
    value={revisions}
    onChange={(e) => setRevisions(e.target.value)}
    placeholder="Enter any packaging requirements"
    autoSize={{ minRows: 4, maxRows: 6 }}
    disabled={qalaraEdit}
    ref={focusSheet}
  />
```

And I am triggering this ref onClick of a text on the page with:

```js
onClick={() => {
    focusSheet.current.focus();
    editSheetRef.current.scrollIntoView(
      { behavior: 'smooth',block: "end", inline:"nearest"}
    )}
  }
```

Comment: [antd doesn't appear to *have* a TextArea component](https://ant.design/components/overview/). What component are you actually using?

Comment: @Quentin : using TextArea from Input like const { TextArea } = Input;

Answer (score 0):

The button was getting disabled by some local state and that was why the focus was not working.

Now onClick of CTA, I am changing one state and based on that state's new value, I'm setting the focus for the textarea using:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if(hideSaveForEdit){
      document.getElementById('textAreaView').focus();
    }
  }, [hideSaveForEdit]);
```